# How to vectorize c++ code using vector classes

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, vectorization, sse

I'm pretty new with `SIMD`, so I'm having some trouble understanding how to use vector classes such as `F32vec4` to operate on arrays in parallel.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could walk me through what this code is doing:

```
#include "fvec.h"

void add(float *a, float *b, float *c)    
{
    F32vec4 *av=(F32vec4 *) a;
    F32vec4 *bv=(F32vec4 *) b;
    F32vec4 *cv=(F32vec4 *) c;
    *cv=*av + *bv;
}
```

Taken from [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-vectorize-code-using-cc-classes-on-32-bit-intel-architecture)

So `av`, `bv`, and `cv` are pointers of type `F32vec4` that point to `a`, `b`, and `c`, respectively?

Also, how can an element of `cv` be accessed and stored back into a regular floating point variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact question is. `av`, `bv` and `cv` are pointers to `a`, `b` and `c`, The difference is that we suppose here that `a`, `b` and `c` are pointers to array with four floats whereas `av`, `bv` and `cv` are pointers to arrays with a single F32vec4.

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't want to access a single element of `cv` and if you did you would just use `c` instead. That said, it is possible. `F32vec4` is really just a wrapper for `__m128` which is an intrinsic variable type for the architecture's multimedia registers. It's not good practice to set/get individual elements of these register because this would be a serial operation and defeat the purpose of the vector operation. If you really have to, the [] operator of `F32vec4` is overloaded; this will cast the the intrinsic register to an array of floats and load/store one element from/to a particular element of the array.